# FX Tick Data question

Tags: data, fx

Anyone can tell me what the first column and the last column in this FX tick dataset mean? The first seems like some kind of ID, and what D in the last column mean?

368412956    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:00:03.000    0.8598    0.8604    D

368413005    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:00:58.000    0.8599    0.8605    D

368413022    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:01:06.000    0.8600    0.8606    D

368413102    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:01:37.000    0.8599    0.8605    D

368413110    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:01:42.000    0.8601    0.8607    D

368413262    AUD/CAD    12/30/2007 17:03:55.000    0.8602    0.8608    D

Comment: Can you say where the data set came from? Also, is there a value in the last column that isn't "D"?

Comment: It's from gaincapital. This is a question my friend asks which i tried to help him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first column is just a unique id tagged by Gain; this allows you to separate multiple messages that come in with the same timestamp.

D means "dealable": this means that a trade could take place.  [According to this thread](http://forex-scam.com/general-trading-discussions-forex/26474-gain-error-11-pair-not-dealable.html), Gain is known for not dealing around events like major news announcements.

[Note: In EBS data, which is much more reliable, "D" means "deal" (or trade) while "Q" means "quote".  This is an entirely different meaning from in the Gain data.]

Comment: What would Q mean then?

Comment: @Andy See my update; sorry, I was confused based on my prior experience with FX data.  Don't use Gain myself, I use major banks and ECN's; Gain tends to serve retail clients more than institutions.  See Mebane Faber's recent critique of Gain and company: http://www.mebanefaber.com/2011/04/03/currency-trading/.

Comment: For reference: a quote is the top of the book bid/ask spread provided by a market maker or limit order book.  In this case, all of Gain's data is quote data: they don't seem to provide transaction prices.

Comment: Shane, how can I access EBS data? After cleaning it up I am planning to use GAIN data for backtesting. Can you comment on how reliable is gain's data for backtesting purposes? Can you suggest any other sources (non-commercial). Thanks!

Comment: The GAIN data is quite unreliable (unordered and with gaps). The best place for free data I have found is dukascopy: http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/data_feed/historical/ , although it would be great to see how that compares to a _real_ provider.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the **[original headers](http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/2011/03%20March/.%5CAUD_CAD_Week2.zip)** for some recent data we have something like this:

```
lTid    cDealable   CurrencyPair    RateDateTime    RateBid RateAsk
```

So `D` would seem to be "**dealable**", but to be honest I couldn't find an example of a `non-D` value in the files (I haven't looked thorougly though), so I don't really get it.

The cryptic ID, is a **tick identifier**, but no information is given as to how it is really constructed. I assume it should be automatically incremented on every incoming tick (across any currency).

If that's true, then the actual data seems to be sorted by `date/time` column (if you look at some recent files, some ticks occur with equal time and are out of order when comparing IDs). So you should verify it first.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything better on this.